# Restrict Windows share to some users

Tags: samba

Environment: Windows 7 machine, Ubuntu 16.04 machine and others.
I have create a shared directory in windows called formation. In my network there are many other machines. However, I want to restrict formation to be accessible only to my user on ubuntu 16.04. 
I have installed samba on ubuntu 16.04.
How can I restrict permissions as explained above?

Comment: Do you use Active Directory?  Are your Ubuntu machines on the domain?

Comment: When you define teh share in the `smb.conf` you can specify valid users, which can also specify a group.  Either limit it to your user, or limit it to a group that your user is the only member of... personally I'd go group so in the future others can be added if really needed